# Sonata Admin: Use multiple document classes (types)

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

**As you know, all God's creatures are different**. They best fit into a *non-relational* database like [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb). Let's say I have a `ZooCollecion` with different `Animal` Document Objects.

How can I use [sonata-admin](/questions/tagged/sonata-admin), to **change the document class** with a simple "type" select-menu (or something related) ?

[image: Sonata Admin - Demonstrate a "type" select-menu]

`Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`

```
services:
    animal.admin.page:
        class: %animal.admin.class%
        arguments: [null, %animal.class%, null] # Is this the key ?
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: doctrine_mongodb, group: Zoo, label: Animals }
```

Animal - `Acme/DemoBundle/Document/Animal` (**base document**):

```
/**
 * Class representing Animals
 *
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="zoo_animals", 
 *  repositoryClass="Acme\DemoBundle\Repository\ZooRepository")
 */
class Animal
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Hash
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Type type should not be blank.")
     */
    protected $type;

    ...
}
```

[image: Elephant Icon - (c) VisualPharm visualpharm.com] Elephant - `Acme/DemoBundle/Document/Elephant` (*extends the base document*):

```
/**
 * Class representing Elephants
 */
class Elephant extends Animal
{
    ...
}
```

[image: Turtle Icon - (c) VisualPharm visualpharm.com] Turtle - `Acme/DemoBundle/Document/Turtle` (*extends the base document*):

```
/**
 * Class representing Turtles
 */
class Turtle extends Animal
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good example of that type of implementation in the admin would be the product creation admin in [sonata ecommerce](https://github.com/sonata-project/ecommerce)
(see the createAction in the ProductAdminController: https://github.com/sonata-project/ecommerce/blob/master/src/ProductBundle/Controller/ProductAdminController.php).

Basically what we did was override the AdminController through the service definition (see https://github.com/sonata-project/ecommerce/blob/master/src/ProductBundle/Resources/config/admin.xml), which allowed us to override the createAction to begin with a type selection, and then edit the form according to this argument (here it's not a type per say, but a product provider ; but this basically is the same thing).

Comment: Hugo Briand, your links are dead…